# Include query with R package

Tags: r, r-package

I have a SQL query that I would like to ship with an R package I have built, but when I try to include it in the `inst` or `extdata` or `data` folders inside my R package I don't know how to get the function to reference it. An example might be this: query file is `myQuery.sql`

```
runDbQuery = function(){
   queryfile = 'folder/myQuery.sql'
   query = readChar(queryfile, file.info(queryfile)$size)
   require(RODBC)
   channel <- odbcConnect("mydb", uid = "uid", 
    pwd = "pwd")
  dbResults = sqlQuery(channel = channel, query = query, as.is = T)
  close(channel)
  return(dbResults)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put `.sql` files I use in packages in `/inst/sql` and then get the path to them in functions via:

```
system.file("sql/myquery.sql",package = "mypackage")
```